# Loopback: PersistedModel.findById() gives not final instance. Methods like save() not existing

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback

In an "afterRemote"-Hook i want to find a specific model and change an attribute:

```
Team.afterRemote('prototype.__create__messages', function(ctx, message, next) {
    var Message = Team.app.models.message;

   // Promises.all not required, just for debugging (i removed other code)
    const promises = Promise.all( [
        Message.findById(message.id),
    ] )

    promises.then( function(result) {
        console.log("FOUND Message ", result);

        // here i'd like to change an attribute and save the model back to database
        console.log(typeof result.save); // will print undefined
    });
```

How could i manipulate the found entity and save it? Save()-Method is not present. All in all findById delivers a plain JSON-object, not a real PersistedModel-Instance.

The Model was defined as:

`{
  "name": "message",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "strict": false,
  "idInjection": false,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },`

Database is a mongoDB.

Comment: `findById` actually must return a model instance. http://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#persistedmodel-findbyid You should probably log a bug here: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/new

Comment: Ah, looks like you have - https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/3521 :)

Answer (score 2):

Loopback model functions support promises as well. Your code can be rewritten as below.

```
var Message = Team.app.models.message;

Message.findById(message.id).then( function(result) {
    console.log("FOUND Message ", result);
    console.log(typeof result.save);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
console.log("FOUND Message ", result[0]);
console.log(typeof result[0].save);
```

Root cause: Please take a look of [**Promise.all**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) documentation

> Promise.all is fulfilled asynchronously. In all cases, the returned
>   promise is fulfilled with an **array** containing all the values of the
>   iterable passed as argument (also non-promise values).

So your case, `result` is an array like `[messageObject]`.

Hope that my answer can help :)